# Output Japanese characters with git bash

Tags: python, character-encoding, git-bash

I am trying to run a Python script with Japanese characters using git bash.

`python test_print_jp.py`

The code executed by this script is:

```
jp_str = u'ァアィイゥ'
print(jp_str)
```

While I am able to print the Japanese string in a notebook, I am not able to print the same string from git bash terminal.

The error is
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>`

I have tried changing the locale setting in `.bash_profile`:

```
export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8
```

I have also tried modifying the string encoding:

```
str = u'ァアィイゥ'
print(str.encode('shift_jis'))
```

While there is no more error with the second solution, the output of the original string becomes `b'\x83@\x83A\x83B\x83C\x83D'`

I have also tried modifying the setting from the interface:

[change_locale_setting_with_git_bash_interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3t25.png)

Is there a way to print the original Japanese string from git bash terminal?

Thank you for any inputs and suggestions :)

Comment: it seems you run WIndows - so maybe Windows put this text in file as `ISO` or `CP1250` instead of  `UTF-8`

Comment: I tried to run `b'\x83@\x83A\x83B\x83C\x83D'.decode()` to get back string with Japan UTF-8 chars but it gives error. I have to problem to run `print('ァアィイゥ')` on Linux which uses `UTF-8` but if I use `u' アィイゥ'.encode('shift_jis')` then I get `b' \x83A\x83B\x83C\x83D'` which can mean that your editor put text in different encoding.

Comment: @furas: Yes, you are right, I am using git bash on Windows. 

I also just tested printing a Japanese string with a Linux machine (`python test_print_jp.py`, where `test_print_jp.py` contains Japanese characters). There was no problem in printing the string. No encoding is required. It seems to be a Windows-specific problem...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hints from @furas, I found an answer to the posted problem. It was not sufficient to just change the locale setting for the git bash application, I have to also change the locale setting in Windows as well.

[image: Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Change System Locale]

After making this change and restarting windows, the Japanese characters are rendered correctly in the terminal without needing to use encoding.

```
jp_str = 'ァアィイゥ'
print(jp_str)
```

The output on terminal will also be: `ァアィイゥ`

**Note:**
I should also mention that using the beta version of `utf-8` encoding for worldwide language support, as shown in the following screenshot is also not sufficient.

[image: beta UNICODE UTF-8 for worldwide language support]

Although there is no more `UnicodeEncodeError`, the original Japanese characters become gibberish on the output.